# Issue with filter inside of geom in ggplot. "comparison (1) is possible only for atomic and list types"

Tags: r, ggplot2, dplyr

I have a simple two-column time-series dataset that looks like this:

```
Date        Signups
22-Feb-18   601         
23-Feb-18   500         
24-Feb-18   6000
...
27-Apr-22   999         
28-Apr-22   998         
29-Apr-22   123         
30-Apr-22   321
```

And I'm trying to make a simple line chart that shows the monthly total over time and then a point at the most recent month. But the filter within the geom_point is giving me a hard time. Here's what I have:

```
library(tidyverse)
library(scales)
library(lubridate)

signups %>% 
  mutate(Date = dmy(Date)) %>% 
  group_by(month(Date), year(Date)) %>% 
  mutate(month = paste0(month(Date),"-",year(Date))) %>% 
  mutate(month = my(month)) %>% 
  mutate(monthly_total = sum(signups)) %>% 
  ungroup() %>% 
  dplyr::filter(month >= "2018-03-01") %>% 
  ggplot(aes(month, monthly_total)) +
  geom_line() + 
  geom_point(data = signups %>% dplyr::filter(month == "2022-03-01")) +
  expand_limits(y = 0, x = as.Date(c("2018-03-01", "2024-03-01"))) +
  scale_y_continuous(labels = comma)
```

If I comment out the geom_point it gives me the line chart that I'm looking for. But when the geom_point is included here it throws this error:

```
Error in dplyr::filter(., month == "2022-03-01") : 
Caused by error in `month == "2022-03-01"`:
! comparison (1) is possible only for atomic and list types
```

I've tried using subset instead of filter and it didn't help. Let me know if you have any suggestions. Thanks!

Comment: `month` doesn't exist in the original `signups` tibble.  It's created earlier in the pipe.  That's why the filter fails.  It's also bad practice to name your columns with identifiers that match functions (eg `month` and `year`).

Answer (score 0):

The comment from Limey got us there. Here's what I needed to do:

```
signups <- signups %>% 
  mutate(Date = dmy(Date)) %>% 
  mutate(just_month = paste0(month(Date),"-",year(Date))) %>% 
  mutate(just_month = my(just_month)) %>% 
  group_by(month(Date), year(Date)) %>% 
  mutate(monthly_total = sum(signups)) %>% 
  ungroup()

signups %>% 
  dplyr::filter(just_month >= "2018-03-01") %>% 
  ggplot(aes(just_month, monthly_total)) +
  geom_line(aes(just_month, monthly_total)) + 
  geom_point(data = dplyr::filter(signups, just_month == "2022-04-01")) +
  expand_limits(y = 0, x = as.Date(c("2018-03-01", "2024-03-01"))) +
  scale_y_continuous(labels = comma)
```